# Error on pressing enter key while md autocomplete list is processing

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to block or haze the background form or block the enter key when "md autocomplete" list is loading in angular? If i press enter while the list is loading then facing "HTTP error -1".

In my scenario, there is service call to database on every alphabet key you press on the field.

Here is my code Snippet:

JS:

```
function querySearch (searchText) {
        return $http
   .get(BACKEND_URL + '/items/' + searchText)
   .then(function(data) {
     // Map the response object to the data object.
     return data;
     });
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" 
md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: hi Shivendra put some more context into your qustion . what lib you are used and if you can put some code that  Which describes the code around

Comment: Hi Pery, Just added the code snippet, please let me know if any suggestions.